# For loop wont run all the way through

Tags: c++

My for loop stops at the 88th number which I find very odd. I cannot figure out why it is doing this. It doesnt exit the for loop and it doesnt continue reading any numbers. Im very confused.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

double distanceCalc(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return sqrt(((x2-x1) * (x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1)));
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    double x, y, min = 10000000;
    vector<double> xCoor;
    vector<double> yCoor;
    while (cin >> n && n != 0)
    {
        int numPairs = n;
        cout << numPairs << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++)
        {
            cin >> x >> y;
            cout << x << " " << y << " " << i << endl;
            xCoor.push_back(x);
            yCoor.push_back(y);

        }
        if (n == 1)
        {
            min = 1000000000;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                double temp = distanceCalc(xCoor[i], yCoor[i], xCoor[j], yCoor[j]);
                if (temp < min)
                {
                    min = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        (min < 10000) ? printf("%.4f\n", min) : printf("INFINITY\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the input im using is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SNZAVh2lkiih-RSQRa9nH5Oj6RD-fw5Z

Comment: It's not normal to use a for-loop to read user input. Use a while-loop.

Comment: I had it as while (numPairs--) and (numPairs >= 0) / (numPairs > 0) with a numPairs-- at the end of the loop and a (cin >> x >> y) and it all did the same thing.

Comment: I just tried your code (copy and paste) and it worked fine, in that I was not able to reproduce your results of stopping at the 88th number.  It read 646 lines for me.  Perhaps the "not relevant" code you omitted is relevant?

Comment: I just pasted your code into the main function at onlinegdb.com and pasted your input into the input and it ran fine.  The only things I added were the main function and includes for iostream and vector.  So that means some of your other code is making it stop.

Comment: I updated the question to include all of my code

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/IxOdCH).

Answer (score 0):

Both I and others have tried your code, and have not been able to reproduce the problem.

It is of course *possible* that there is something wrong with your C++ installation, but a more common problem when these things happen is that you are running an older version of the program than the one you think you are running. So check carefully that you are actually re-compiling the code after each change, and that you are really using the source file that you think. You could, for example, add an extra printout to the program, and see if you find it in the output.

Also check that you are using the input file you think you are using. Perhaps you are really reading another version of the input, and that one has some garbage after the first 88 numbers?

Comment: I think it was a problem with my machine but I was able to fix the issue by converting it over to java and it worked flawlessly. Thanks for the help.